# volume of parallelepiped with undefined angles

Tags: volume

The edges of parallelepiped that have a common vertex are a, b and c. The angle between a and b is β, and the angle that the circumferential edge c forms with each of the edges a and b is acute with a magnitude of α with α>2β. Find the volume of the parallelepiped.

Comment: 1) Which information is hided in the adjective "circumferencial" ? 2) What are your attempts ? Where are you blocked ?

Comment: circumferential part was negligible I just mean that the angles locked between (b,c)and (a,c) are equal. So when I tried to solve it I made a perpendicular from the other end of  edge c to the base, defined by a and b,which served as a hight. I got that h= c*sin(α) and the area of the base - sin(β)*a*b . I tried to check if it is correct and I made a simulation with some angles and side lengths but I got very different results compared with the product derived from the standard formula for the volume of a parallelepiped V = abc * √ (1 + 2*cos(α)*cos(β)*cos(γ) - cos²(α) - cos²(β) - cos²(γ)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote by $\vec{A},\vec{B},\vec{C}$ the vectors issued from the common vertex, with resp. length (=norms) $a,b,c$.

Let us define matrix

$$M=[\vec{A}|\vec{B}|\vec{C}]$$

(in the RHS, columns entries are the coordinates of $\vec{A},\vec{B},\vec{C}$ with respect to a certain orthonormal basis).

It is well known that $\det(M)=V$ (parallelepiped's volume).

Now compute (in close connection with the computations of paragraph "volume" in [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped)) the so-called **"Gram matrix"** of ordered system $(\vec{A},\vec{B},\vec{C})$:

$$M^T M=\begin{pmatrix}\vec{A}\cdot\vec{A}&\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}&\vec{A}\cdot\vec{C}\\
\vec{B}\cdot\vec{A}&\vec{B}\cdot\vec{B}&\vec{B}\cdot\vec{C}\\
\vec{C}\cdot\vec{A}&\vec{C}\cdot\vec{B}&\vec{C}\cdot\vec{C}
\end{pmatrix}$$

where the dots are for dot product.

Using the given angles  :

$$M^T M=\begin{pmatrix}a^2&ab \cos \beta&ac \cos \alpha\\
ab \cos \beta&b^2&bc \cos \alpha\\
ac \cos \alpha&bc \cos \alpha&c^2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Equating the determinants of the LHS and the RHS (remember that $\det(M^TM)=\det(M)^2$) :

> $$V^2=a^2b^2c^2(1+2 \cos^2 \alpha \cos \beta-2\cos^2 \alpha-\cos^2 \beta).$$

Remark : Condition $\alpha > 2\beta$ hasn't been used.

Comment: I have added the term "Gram matrix" and made a remark at the end.